# Complete Stable version of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Help me in selecting Ubuntu, which one version of Ubuntu version is fully stable?

Comment: All current released versions of Ubuntu are stable. The in-development version is the only "non-stable" version, and it's not yet released. If by "fully stable" you mean has Long Term Support, then the latest current LTS release is 14.04.3.

Comment: @dobey: I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current full stable version of Ubuntu is **14.04.3 LTS**.

Download the recommended edition of [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

The next stable version 16.04 LTS will be released in April.

LTS stands for Ubuntu long term support, which is five years.

In this period Ubuntu gets security and maintenance updates.

Comment: When in doubt always use LTS - that's what pros always say :D